# Getting the attribute holder of an attribute

Tags: python

Is a reference exists from an attribute to the attribute holder?
Here is an example what I mean:

```
class classA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class classB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=classA()

    def methodB(self):
        print "ClassB-s methodB called"

b=classB()
a=b.a
```

Is it possible to reference b from a? I like to call methodB from a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.

When you initialize `b.a`, it becomes a reference to a `classA` object:

```
>>> b.a
<__main__.classA object at 0x7feeb904df10>
```

To call the method, you *could* pass the parent object to `classA`:

```
>>> class classA(object):
...    def __init__(self, parent):
...        self.parent = parent
...    
...    def method(self):
...        self.parent.methodB()
...
>>>
>>> class classB(object):
...    def __init__(self):
...        self.a=classA(self)
...
...    def methodB(self):
...        print "ClassB-s methodB called"
...
>>> b = classB()
>>> a = b.a
>>> a.method()
ClassB-s methodB called
```

From there, you have access to the whole parent.

Comment: So no any other way, then passing the parent instance to the constructor of classA?